# What is this aircraft that has both piston and jet engines?

Tags: jet-engine, aircraft-identification, piston-engine

A friend sent me this picture of a trimotor aircraft with what looks like two radial engines and a jet in the middle. He didn't know what is was and neither do I. Anyone recognize it?

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is a double-hulled ["YAK-110"](http://inspire.eaa.org/2017/11/30/because-they-could/) (which is two [Yak-55's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakovlev_Yak-55)), it was only recently completed and will be at Oskosh 2018 (and so will I, so I may be able to add additional pictures in August).

[Here is an article about it](https://www.avweb.com/avwebflash/news/Double-Yak-Coming-To-Oshkosh-230212-1.html).

Here is another video with the jet engine at its first airshow (and the picture you have is a screenshot from it):

It also isn't the only aircraft set up this way (jet/piston), the [Screamin Sasquatch](http://eaavintage.org/the-screamin-sasquatch/) is another airshow aircraft converted to have both.

Comment: I have control!  No!.. I have control!     You had control yesterday!... This is left cockpit control day!  No!... It's right cockpit control day!

Comment: @JohnK Sounds like a reasonable question.

Comment: Of course it was.  I was making a joke about the configuration.

Comment: @JohnK - "The left cockpit is for immediate loading and unloading of pilots only. There is no stopping in the right cockpit." "No, the right cockpit is for loading of pilots and there is no stopping in a LEFT cockpit!". "The LEFT cockpit has ALWAYS been for loading and unloading of pilots. There's never stopping in the RIGHT cockpit!". "Don't you tell me which cockpit is for loading, and which cockpit is for stopping!"

Comment: At least on the Twin Mustang the right side cockpit was the radar guy so there wasn't any question who was flying.

Comment: Not only the Screamin' Sasquatch (what a name!) but how about the [B-36 Peacemaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convair_B-36_Peacemaker)?